# Can't force use of integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm on 16.10 and I can't force the use of my integrated Intel GPU. System always uses my NVIDIA GPU. I've installed the latest NVIDIA driver (378) and I can't see PRIME profiles in the NVIDIA X Server Settings. Additionally, when I try to use `prime-select` to select the Intel profile I get the following message

```
the current EGL alternative in use are ['nvidia-378', 'nvidia-378']
selecting nvidia-378-prime for the intel profile
```

All the solutions online involve just installing the newest drivers which I already have.

In my "additional drivers" settings I have the NVIDIA 378 selected and the "Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUS from intel-microcode" selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

For posterity the issue was fixed by going into my BIOS and setting my iGPU to be the primary display adapter. After that, I had issues with starting X. I was able to fix this by removing `nomodeset` from my default grub start command and replacing it with `i915.modeset=1`. After that I updated my grub and initramfs with `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Then when I rebooted it worked.

EDIT 2:

Removed `i915.modeset=1` from grub start command. Turns out just removing `nomodeset` was all I needed to do. Additionally, prime profiles is now available in my NVIDIA X Server Settings.

Comment: Is it a laptop? What is the GPU?

Comment: Not a laptop. GPU is a 970.

Comment: Why do you need the `i915.modeset=1`? It is default anyway.

Comment: You were right. It wasn't needed.

Comment: Prime profiles are available, but useless in your case, I am afraid. You can remove `nvidia-prime` from a desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a desktop system, you can't switch to your integrated GPU using any software.

`prime-select` works only with mobile GPUs with Optimus technology.

The only way you can do it is to plug the monitor cable into the another HDMI, or whatever, linked to your motherboard.

You can also switch the primary GPU in your BIOS settings.

Comment: I've been testing with with one monitor plugged into my GPU and one monitor plugged into my MOBO. At least once I tried having nothing plugged into the GPU and I got no signal on either monitor, but switching a cable over the GPU gave me a signal. The system was still trying to use the GPU even when nothing was plugged into it.

Comment: How do you know that the system is trying to use the Nvidia when there is no monitor there?

Comment: Shutdown. Move both cables to MOBO. Start machine. Black screens. Without turning off the machine I move a cable to GPU. Voila, picture.

Comment: You can probably switch the primary GPU in BIOS.

Comment: Hadn't thought of this. I'll try this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: So, the system is now trying to use the iGPU, but my X isn't working. Log here: http://pastebin.com/uB4EaipE

Comment: Issue was I had `nomodeset` as a boot option in grub. Changed it to `i915.modeset=1`, `sudo update-grub`, `sudo update-initramfs -u` (not sure if necessary), rebooted and it worked.

Comment: `nomodeset` is only a temporary solution when the system does not boot. I do not think you need any extra options at all.

Comment: I will try this as well. I remember putting it in to get my live stick/installation to work and didn't realize I should've removed it later.